# Listening logcat and do an action if exception throws?

Tags: android, logcat

I have a java code like this:

```
public class Automation {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        try
        {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "-s", "4df1f91a2b6b5fb9", "install", "C:\\Users\\lenovo 01\\Documents\\android\\CELLOGRAF_LG.apk", "am", "start", "-n", "tr.bm.android.lg.cellograf/.activities.SplashScreen");
            Process pc = pb.start();
            pc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Installed");

            pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "shell", "am", "start", "-n", "tr.bm.android.lg.cellograf/.activities.SplashScreen");
            pc = pb.start();
            pc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Started");


            pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "shell", "am", "force-stop", "tr.bm.android.lg.cellograf");
            pc = pb.start();
            pc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Terminated");

            pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "shell", "pm", "uninstall", "tr.bm.android.lg.cellograf");
            pc = pb.start();
            pc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Uninstalled");              
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do something like:
if any exception is thrown in the logcat in 30 seconds, I want to send a message that apk is corrupted.
I can make the apk is terminated and uninstalled after 30 seconds but I have to listen the logcat for any exception.
Is this possible or this can't be done with java code?

Comment: Exceptions are meant to be handled safely and you can catch them in your code. In android, it is recommended to remove any logcat statements before publishing your app as it is meant for debugging your application

Comment: I won't publish the app to market. My company needs a very specific application to control if an application was made fully stable. I'm wondering can I listen logcat from my java code for an exception. Or do I have to do this manually?